# Paypal return to merchant link and form submission

Tags: paypal

I have an integration set up with paypal website payments pro in the UK.  The integration is set up not to auto-return and PDT is turned off so the customer's payment confirmation is displayed on the paypal website.  Thats' OK.  My problem is the link on this confirmation page to go back to the merchant website (which just goes to the homepage - not an SSL URL) produces a warning in the browser that form data is being passed from a secure page to an non-secure page.  Is there a way of turning off the passing of form data with this link?  It's only going to the homepage so is not necessary, and the appearance of the warning will only worry customers.

Thanks,

Glynn.

Answer (score 0):

There is not anyway to turn this warning off, the only option would be to have the return URL set up as https://.